# How to test the speed of Node + Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am performing a simple update request for 1 row in the database in a loop.
I use the library 'pg-native'.

```
function testPostgres(){
    const moment = require('moment-timezone')
    const Client = require('pg-native')
    const client = new Client()
    client.connect('postgres://postgres:postgres@host:5432/postgres', function(err) {
        if(err) throw err

        const moment1 = moment()
        for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            let rows = client.querySync('update json_test set data = data || \'{"SkillChance": 1}\', count =count+1 where id =$1',[1])

        }
        const moment2 = moment()
        const diff = moment2.diff(moment1, 'seconds')
        console.log(diff) //

    })
}
```

This code (1000 updates) executes in 14 seconds. 
A similar operation (update) for the Node + Mongoose bundle works in 1 second.
What is wrong I am doing Postgres?

PS I understand that synchronous operations in a real project are not used. I use querySync only for speed testing.

Comment: ummm , querySync?  _Sync_?

Comment: did you create the index on postgres?

Comment: @AyushGupta Yes,  in this example Sync. But the following code gives exactly the same result - 14 seconds per 1000 operations:

await client.query()

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza 
No, I did not add an index. I assumed that it is not necessary if there is only 1 row in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Promise.all` to run your queries parallelly, it should help you reduce your execution time by a bunch.

```
async function testPostgres() {
  const moment = require('moment-timezone')
  const Client = require('pg-native')
  const client = new Client()
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.connect('postgres://postgres:postgres@host:5432/postgres', (err) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve()
    })
  })

  const arrayOf1000 = new Array(1000).fill(0)
  const moment1 = moment()

  await Promise.all(arrayOf1000.map(() =>
    client.query('update json_test set data = data || \'{"SkillChance": 1}\', count =count+1 where id =$1', [1])
  ))


  const moment2 = moment()
  const diff = moment2.diff(moment1, 'seconds')
  console.log(diff) //
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is strange, but the execution time remains the same ..